# Duplicate record from table remove in sql when there is joining of two tables and return single record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `organization` and `organization_relation` table where `organization_id` is common for both tables.

`organization_relation` table has `org_type_cd` column which can be different but it can point to same `organization_id` in main table.
So, if there are 2 `org_type_cd` with same `organization_id` then I need to return only 1 record instead of returning `org_name` same twice.

**Query Used currently:**

```
SELECT O.ORGANIZATION_ID, O.ACTIVE_IND, O.ORG_NAME, T.ORG_TYPE_CD 
FROM ORGANIZATION O 
INNER JOIN ORGANIZATION_RELATION T
ON T.ORGANIZATION_ID  =  O.ORGANIZATION_ID 
WHERE T.ORG_TYPE_CD = 2581973089.00 
OR T.ORG_TYPE_CD =  2576962393.00
```

**Current Output:**

| ORGANIZATION_ID | ACTIVE_IND | ORG_NAME | ORG_TYPE_CD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3348036 | 1 | APHR_AUTOORG5 | 2581973089 |
| 3348037 | 1 | APHR_AUTO_ORG | 2581973089 |
| 3348037 | 1 | **MRD_ORG** | **2576962393** |
| 3348037 | 1 | **MRD_ORG** | **2581973089** |
| 3348037 | 1 | RVRSWEDUNIT | 2576962393 |
| 3904035 | 1 | RVR CAO Two | 2576962393 |

I am using inner join here. This query is returning me MRD_ORG twice since for both `org_type_cd` it has MRD_ORG. Instead I want to return it only once.

I tried adding distinct, but distinct works for entire select statement so it does not work. Is there any approach we can consider and return MRD_ORG only once in the output.

Comment: You only want one, but how do you want to decide which one? Lowest code, highest code, newest record using a timestamp column, use a magic 8 ball to decide?

Comment: I have corrected table. MRD_ORG is there for both org_type_cd values 2576962393 and 2581973089 but for same organization_id and active_ind value. So i want to return single row instead of two rows for the same

Comment: Read my comment again. ***How do you want to decide which row you want?***

Comment: Which of the two `ORG_TYPE_CD` values do you want to keep, and why?

Comment: Does not make much sense to remove it or give it status as duplicate if "some feature of the row (another column) will always be unique to inserted it into the table". It then by proxy the difference is not a duplicate, and that must make "3348037" quite something else. That appears a bad way to define duplicate.

Comment: Based on latest created record among those we need to filter out one record if there is duplicate @MatBailie

Comment: ORG_TYPE_CD is in second table. I am not concerned about that column. Instead in mail table ORGANIZATION i want to check latest created one @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: 1) You want to account for a column not mentioned in your question (latest created timestamp of some kind). So, please edit your question to include the data in ***both*** of your two tables, and read [mre]. 2) You say you're not concerned with the column ORG_TYPE_CD, so please explain to us why it's in your query and output and whether it can/should be removed?

Answer (score -1):

To remove the duplicates, I would do a pre-query of DISTINCT Organizations, then join to get the name such as

```
select
      o.*
   from
      ( select distinct
              organization_id
           from
              ORGANIZATION_RELATION
           where
              org_type_cd in ( 2581973089, 2576962393 ) 
      ) r
         JOIN Organization o
            on r.organization_id = o.organization_id
```

Comment: The OP specifically selects the ORG_TYPE_CD from the ORGANIZATION_RELATION table, but this does not. Also, the type of query you propose is more effectively expressed and solved when using EXISTS(). Finally, though its likely the join is the cause of the duplication, it is still completely possible the duplication originates in the ORGANIZATION table, and that there is actually a 1:1 relation with ORGANIZATION_RELATION.

Comment: @MatBailie, this absolutely does.  The prequery "r" alias is directly from the org relation table for the org_type_code of the two IDs in question.  Once a unique is pulled, only then join to the org table.  just shows multiple ways to answer a query.

Comment: You've assumed it's unique in ORGANIZATION, you have not verified that a lack of uniqueness is the underlying problem. And you still do Not select all the columns the OP selected.

Comment: @MatBailie, I believe the OP ONLY included the org type code from the relation table to show WHY the duplicate name.  All other columns are from the organization only.  Appearing to want a list of all organizations that hit "whatever" criteria to be contacted so they have a single list of orgs to contact regardless of which part of the criteria was qualified.